# ID is undefined when using a radio input field - Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, graphql, liquid

I hope you can help me on this.

I have a liquid page that consist of Vue scripts as well then in my page I have a list of radio selection. This radio selection is rendered via Liquid tag and graphQL results.

Now my problem is whenever I click the submit button or choose an option on my radio the console throws me an error showing that there is a specific ID that is undefined.

https://cbo.d.pr/3i2mre

If I changed from radio to checkboxes I didn't have this issue.

https://cbo.d.pr/Y99Itp

Can you help me spot where's my error on this? Console error message doesn't provide more details about the issue that is why I am assuming that the error is on ID.

Here's my code:

On my form I have this loop of radio

```
<div class="cell large-6">
    <ul class="product_category_selections">
        {% graphql industry_list = 'get_homepage_industry_list' %}
        {% for industry_item in industry_list.items.results %}
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" id="{{ industry_item.id }}" value="{{ industry_item.id }}" v-model="selected_industry" /> {{ industry_item.properties.name }}
                </label>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="text" v-model="selected_industry" name="form[properties_attributes][industry]" />
    </ul>
</div>
```

then below is the scripting part

```
new Vue({
    el: '#request-sample-form-app',
    delimiters: ["!!", "!!"],
    data: {
        selected_industry: [],
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        contact_number: '',
        email: '',
        company_name: '',
        address_1: '',
        address_2: '',
        city: '',
        state_province: '',
        zip_postal_code: '',
        country: '',
        application_description: ''
    },
    methods: {
        initApp: function() {
            console.log('App initialized!');
            this.country = 'Australia';
        },
        validateRequestSampleForm: function() {

            var error = "";

            if (!this.selected_industry) {
                error += '<p>Please choose an industry</p>';
            }

            if (!this.first_name) {
                error += '<p>Please enter first name</p>';
            }

            // SOME ERROR VALIDATIONS ...
            if (error) {
                Swal.fire({
                    type: "error",
                    title: "Error",
                    html: error
                })
                return;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        },

        validateForm: function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#request_sample_form_application").submit(); 
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.initApp();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue,

Tried  to use onchange event method but the issue is still the same but when I looked in the radio tag I don't have a name attribute set.

After adding the name attribute it finally solves the issue. 
For now I don't have any idea how the simple name attribute brakes my script.

```
 <div class="cell large-6">
                    <ul class="product_category_selections">
                        {% graphql industry_list = 'get_homepage_industry_list' %}
                        {% for industry_item in industry_list.items.results %}
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="selected_industry_name" id="{{ industry_item.id }}" value="{{ industry_item.id }}" v-model="selected_industry" /> {{ industry_item.properties.name }}
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <input type="text" v-model="selected_industry" name="form[properties_attributes][industry]" />
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

screenshot: https://cbo.d.pr/ZWox9k